# jQuery-media only fetches external content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the [jQuery media plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/media/) to display HTML and PDF documents on my webpage. The plugin will load any externally hosted PDF/HTML with no issues. However, when I try to provide a URL to my application which returns the file content, it never attempts to fetch the URL.

I have tried a relative URL path (/ajax/...) and a full URL path (protocol, port & all) to the app view.

I have tested the URL I want the application to call by providing the URL to the browser and it properly returns the PDF document.

Anyone have an idea to force the plugin to fetch the URL I am providing?

Comment: Do you get an error on screen? If not can you run it in Chrome and bring up the Javascript Console to see if there are errors?

Comment: I do not get any errors/warnings in the JS console. With the network tab open I also notice no outgoing request like I get with an external URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after rewriting the jquery.media plugin due to its complex nature, Greg and I found the solution.  Effectively, the extension type must be specified in the url.  For example the url '/mypdfs/my.pdf' would work but the url 'mypdfs/123' will not because jquery.media cannot determine the file type.  A way to get around this is to make an ajax HEAD request and get the content type and then pass the appropriate extension type as an option to the media call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    async: true,
    url: "http://myurl.com/file",
    success: function(message, text, response){
        var contentType = response.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
        // Map content types to extension type
        $('.media').media({type: extensionType});
    }
});
```

Also, Malsup's library seems to be unmaintained.  We did a rewrite of the library which can currently be found [here](https://github.com/timmartin19/jMedia).  We will be adding mapping Content-Type to file extensions as time permits so that this can be more flexibly implemented. Feel free to make a pull request.